# Required logging of Method calling with time consumed by that Method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Required support to log the method entry and exit with the time consumed by that method, is it possible with the postsharp to log, our application is in Framework 4.6.1 and we have used  Postsharp 6.5.3 trial version as of now to check.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.